# Code creating empty database... why??? :(

Tags: java, sqlite, try-catch

I am at start of creating application that uses SQLite. I am experimenting with 3 packages, model, view and controller. Application is working, but I wanted to write code to handle situation when for some reason database can't be found (changed name, not existing etc). I managed to get a MessageDialog informing user of error (not happy with that solution as well, to be honest) but program after displaying it creates empty database file "expenses.db", no table inside which I don't want. I just want message to user.

I tried simple try-catch block instead of try-with-resources, application still creating 0 kb expenses.db file. I didn't created constructors for Connect() and DBController(), didn't knew what to put in them so used default ones.

Connect class in package model:

```
public class Connect {
    public Connection connect() {
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "У реду");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:expenses.db";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "There is a problem connecting database.\n"
                    + "Check does database \"Expenses.db\" exist",
                    "Connecting error",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            conn = null; 
        } //this catch never get executed, don't know why :(
        return conn;
    }
}
```

and DBController class in package controller:

```
public class DBController {

Connect dbConn = new Connect();
public void insert(String city, String name, String category) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Companies(city, name, category) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        try (Connection conn = dbConn.connect();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                pstmt.setString(1, city);
                pstmt.setString(2, name);
                pstmt.setString(3, category);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "There is a problem connecting database.\n"
                    + "Check does database \"Expenses.db\" exist",
                    "Connecting error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

insert data to database is called from view package:

somewhere at start of class:

```
DBController controller = new DBController();
```

click on the button:

```
btnAdd.addActionListener(e -> {
            controller.insert(cboCity.getSelectedItem().toString(), txtName.getText(), 
                    cboCategory.getSelectedItem().toString());
        });
```

I am still a begginer and I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. When error occur MessageDialog from Connect class is never shown, just one from DBController.

Any suggestions how to fix this code, to inform user in a efficient way that database is missing and prevent app to create empty file?

Thanks in advance

after edit I get following in Console:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: Companies)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:134)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:257)
at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:47)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:30)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:19)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:35)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:241)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:205)
at dakijevstina.controller.DBController.insert(DBController.java:17)
at dakijevstina.view.CompanyData.lambda$1(CompanyData.java:183)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at dakijevstina.view.CompanyData.<init>(CompanyData.java:217)
at dakijevstina.view.MainGUI.showCompanyData(MainGUI.java:89)
at dakijevstina.view.MainGUI$2.lambda$1(MainGUI.java:72)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1020)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1064)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Reason is because can't find database expenses.db. To cause this I changed name of file to expensesTEST.db, but it is still unclear to me why it creating blank expenses.db file. :/

Comment: Do you want your program to automatically create the database if it doesn’t exist?  Or do you want the program to display an error dialog and exit if the database doesn’t exist?

Comment: Second option, just error dialog and exit.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are extremely valuable.  They tell you exactly what’s going wrong, where it’s happening, and usually, why it’s happening.

For this reason, you must never suppress exception information.  Always print or log the full stack trace of any exception you catch.

You should also include a one-line description of the exception in your error dialog.  The toString() method of exceptions provides this.

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "There is a problem connecting database:\n"
            + e + "\n\n"
            + "Check does database \"Expenses.db\" exist",
            "Connecting error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

You will receive more help with your question if you edit it, and include the full stack trace, including any `Caused by:` sections.  Until we see that, we can only guess what your problem is.

**Update:**

It appears the driver will always create the `expenses.db` file (without the Companies table) as soon as you connect to it.  Therefore, you need to perform a check before connecting:

```
Path databaseLocation = Paths.get("expenses.db");

if (Files.exists(databaseLocation)) {
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "There is a problem connecting database:\n"
                + e + "\n\n"
                + "Check does database \"Expenses.db\" exist",
                "Connecting error",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Database file \"" + databaseLocation + "\" does not exist.",
        "Connecting error",
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: This will work perfectly. Thanks for solution and big thanks for tips regarding Exception info.